# mydate+GETUTCDATE()-GETDATE() is returning results for mydate in 2015 but not for 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get results where rowsCreated < '**mydate**+GETUTCDATE()-GETDATE()'.
Results are returing if **mydate** reisdes in 2015 year, but not for 2014 . 
please suggest.

thanks in advance

Comment: A little more info about data in `rowsCreated` and `mydate` value.

Comment: Bewarned that this is generally a bad approach for converting between UTC and local time, because of DST: the result of `GETUTCDATE()-GETDATE()` is based on whether DST is currently in effect, not whether it was in effect at `mydate`.

Answer (score 0):

```
rowsCreated < DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()), mydate)
```

This works regardless of what date/time type mydate is; however, be warned, this doesn't work for every time zone (e.g., Asia/Tehran, Australia/Darwin, Australia/Eucla), as it returns an integer number of hours.

To be safe, you'd probably want:

```
rowsCreated < DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()), mydate)
```